# Class Diagram UML modelling for Events

Tags: python, uml, object-oriented-analysis

There's a module in python called "events" from which we can import an object called "Events".
[URL for events module](https://pypi.org/project/Events/)

Objects can register a callback method to the object, and other objects can invoke the member of the events. E.g. shown below:

```
from events import Events

#Implementation of Events
class EventGroup(Events):
  __events__ = ('eventOne', 'eventTwo', 'eventThree')

eventGroupOne = EventGroup()


#This class subscribes to the events
class Subscriber():
  def __init__(self):
    eventGroupOne.eventOne += self.onEventOne

  def onEventOne(self):
    print("EventOne invoked")


#This class invokes the events
class Invoker():
  def someFunction(self):
    eventGroupOne.eventOne()
```

How can we show the relationship between the classes EventGroup, Subscriber and Invoker in Class Diagram UML?

Comment: Since you use global variables declared in `__main__` you do not have a pure OO approach. So anything would be opinion based on what could be answered here. So I retracted my opion and voted to close.

Comment: @qwerty_so :  There was no need to retract your answer. I started my Class Diagram the same way, but I felt there was a better answer. But, it's your decision, and I respect it.

Comment: Would you mind telling what change in the above code would you suggest to make it OO?

Comment: I beg your pardon, but I maybe asking a very basic question here. Let's forget about __main__ here. What I have done in the above code is imported one module, defined three classes, and instantiated an object. Isn't this enough to create a Class Diagram without violating the OOP?

Comment: No. You use `eventGroupOne` out of nowhere. It's supposed to be an attribute of a class. But it isn't.

Comment: There's a simple way to make it pure: place the global variable in some class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you strictly follow the definitions a class diagram can be showing only used members :

[image]

In that case *eventOne, eventTwo* and *eventThree* are only visible in an object diagram

---

An other way cheating a little is to consider *eventOne, eventTwo* and *eventThree* are properties of *EventGroup* :

[image]

Comment: I like your first approach. Can you provide the meanings of the arrows used in your diagram as the arrows differ somewhat in their meaning at times?

Comment: @sulavshr `<|----` is a generalization corresponding to an inheritance. `<------` are association, I preferred to not to use a composition (`<*>----->`) between *Events* and *_EventSlots* rather than just an association. `<- - - - -` are dependencies

Comment: @bruno,Woww great explanation, answer thanks for sharing.